# DataGridView.Rows.Add has different effects inside of a For loop. Why?

Tags: c#, for-loop, datagridview

I'm confident that the scoping rules of `for` loops aren't relevant here, so I've got no idea what is going on. I'm absolutely confident that I've isolated the problem down to this one line of code, so the context isn't needed. `d` is a `DataGridView` that is used as an input to the method that this code is found in and `c` is a `DataGridViewCellCollection`. I've taken

```cs
d.Rows.Add(DataGridViewCellCollection(c[0].Value.ToString(), c[1].Value.ToString(), c[2].Value.ToString())
```

and replaced it with

```cs
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) d.Rows.Add(c[i].Value.ToString());
```

For reasons unknown to me, these two code blocks aren't identical. What could be causing this? They appear to call the same overload of `Add` and I've found no insight in the debugger.

Comment: They are not identical. The second adds three times.

Comment: @RomanRyzhiy Huh. Perhaps I shouldn't have trusted my IDE. It appears you're right. Any idea how to shorten down ugly lines like my first block of code? The real example as 12 uses of `c[number].Value.ToString()`.

Comment: if the question is a beauty of the code, then forget it

Comment: @RomanRyzhiy You've given me the answer that I needed. I was just trying my luck to learn a bit more.